# ng-repeat and jsTree

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a problem :D I'm using angular 1.4.7 and now I need some treeview. I used jsTree for it but it sees all my ng-repeats as one. Is it a problem bcs of the jsTree or I did something wrong? If it is a problem of jsTree then What do you recommend to use for treeView on angular?

key nodes: The tree is looking fine but when I click one of the elements of it then it just clicks the toppest one.

here the codes:

```
        <div class="col-md4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id='UserGroupTree' >

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in page.treeNodeItems" value='item.UserGroupCode'>{{item.UserGroupName}}
                </li>
            </ul>

            <script>
                $('#UserGroupTree').jstree();
            </script>


        </div>
```

I'm getting my data like this:

```
HttpService.post("user_group", {}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.treeNodeItems = response.data.returnObject;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('error');

});
```

vm.treeNodeItems is an object.

it returns data like this:

```
returnObject: [{UserGroupCode: "UGR_1", UserGroupName: "Admin", UserGroupType: "PUZ"}]
0: {UserGroupCode: "UGR_2", UserGroupName: "Admin", UserGroupType: "PUZ"}
1: {UserGroupCode: "UGR_11", UserGroupName: "Bini", UserGroupType: "AG"}
2: {UserGroupCode: "UGR_32a1209a96c", UserGroupName: "ssd",…}
3: {UserGroupCode: "UGR_8a06aead39b", UserGroupName: "eniz",…}
4: {UserGroupCode: "UGR_ee3029db538", UserGroupName: "sdsd", UserGroupType: null}
```

I took it from chrome so the could be some syntax problems but it is correct and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question, I would recommend [ya-treeview](https://github.com/ca77y/angular-ya-treeview). There is one more [treeView](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) which is pretty simple to use

ya-treeview supports features like event hooks, lazy (async) loading. It's good to use when tree is large, it doesn't even modify the original model. Also, every child has reference to parent, which can be useful in traversing.

Comment: thank you!! I was searching for these kind of things. jsTree just a headache for angular. Now I'm using angular-ivh-treeview. I already did all the job with it so I cant change it again but thank you very much . as soon as possible I will test it too :D thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code to run tree after loading your data

```
HttpService.post("user_group", {}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.treeNodeItems = response.data.returnObject;
    $('#UserGroupTree').jstree();
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: When I do it all my tree disappears... and Im not getting an error??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @crowz.

It is possible to fix without resorting to an angular directive like  @manishrw suggests!

@Abdelrhman Mohamed is correct in that making sure you call $('#UserGroupTree').jstree(); after your tree is fully initialized by angular.  However all the rest of the code supplied may be irrelevant depending on how you have structured things.  In my case I just moved the one line to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the data source is loaded before your jstree is initiated

```
HttpService.post("user_group", {}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.treeNodeItems = response.data.returnObject;
    $timeout(function(){
            $('#UserGroupTree').jstree(),1000
        })
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('error');

});
```